# Where does the form for $1/z$ come from, for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, as claimed by Rudin?

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

On page 13 if Walter Rudin’s *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* the complex number system is proven to be a field. While proving a field axiom for multiplication (M5) an expression for the inverse of a complex number arises.

$$\frac{1}{x}=\left( \frac{a}{a^2+b^2},\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2} \right)$$

I have confirmed that it is valid, but I’m lost on the question of how Rudin came about its derivation.

Comment: The post is looking for motivation, not confirmation that the answer is correct.  I've tried to provide that motivation in my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You can get there in two steps.  First, realize that whenever you multiply a complex number $a+bi$ (where $a, b \in \Bbb R$) by its complex conjugate $a-bi$, you always get the real number $a^2+b^2$.  Second, just multiply that real number by its inverse to get $1$.  Putting the two together, you get:

\begin{align}
(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2 &\Rightarrow \frac{1}{(a+bi)(a-bi)}=\frac{1}{a^2+b^2} \\ &\Rightarrow\frac{1}{a+bi}=\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}i.
\end{align}

In the notation you're probably using, $(0, 1)=i$ and all real numbers $a$ are of the form $(a, 0)$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume Rudin is using $(a,b)$ to refer to the complex number $a+bi$ as we typically see it.

In the $a+bi$ context (with $i^2=-1$), this is easy to see: we multiply $1/z$ by $\overline{z}/\overline{z}$ on top and bottom:

$$\frac{1}{z} \frac{\overline{z}}{\overline{z}} = \frac{a-bi}{(a+bi)(a-bi)}$$

The arithmetic then arrives at the answer.

Rudin I imagine defines
$$
\overline{z} := (a,-b)
\qquad
(a,b)(c,d) := (ac-bd,ad+bc)
\qquad
\frac{(a,b)}{(c,d)}:= \left( \frac{ac+bd}{c^2 +d^2} , \frac{bc-ad}{c^2+d^2} \right)$$

so you can likewise use those definitions and the same idea to justify the answer.